# Convert SQL containing IN statement to chainable LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to convert an MSSQL statement into LINQ. The overall functionality is broken up into many LINQ statements which are combined together, so the result must return type IQueryable.

Included in this question is an example of the schema and data. I am trying to see if the most recent (by DateCreated) value of Number is equal to 400, if so return the Table1Id.

The following is the MSSQL statement.

```
select * from Table1 t1
where 400 in (
  select top 1 t2.Number
  from Table2 t2
  where t2.Table1Id = t1.id
  order by t2.DateCreated desc
)
```

The LINQ I have come up with so far is:

```
//initial query
var query1 = _table1Repository.Table

//chain our query
var query2 = from t1 in query1
            where ((from t2 in _table2Repository.Table
                    where t2.Table1Id == t1.Id
                    orderby t2.DateCreated descending
                    select t2.Number)
                    .Take(1)).Contains(400)
            select t1;

//execute the query (may be more queries between last query and this)
var queryResult = query2.ToList();
```

Though upon executing the following error is thrown:

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Domain.Table2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

```
Table 1 data
| Id |
|----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |

Table 2 data
| Id | DateCreated | Table1Id  |  Number |
|----|------------ |-----------|---------|
| 1  |  1/1/2014   |     1     |   100   |
| 2  |  2/1/2014   |     1     |   200   |
| 3  |  3/1/2014   |     1     |   300   |
| 4  |  1/1/2014   |     2     |   200   |
| 5  |  2/1/2014   |     2     |   300   |
| 6  |  3/1/2014   |     2     |   400   |
| 7  |  1/1/2014   |     3     |   400   |
| 8  |  2/1/2014   |     3     |   300   |
| 9  |  3/1/2014   |     3     |   200   |


Expected result
| Id |
|----|
| 2  |
```

Comment: In your SQL is 100 meant to be a field name? Also i've never seen the syntax IN used with one value before. I'm not sure the sql you have provided shows clearly what you're trying to achieve as your expected results differ from what I'd expect. Pretend I'm being stupid can you describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: ahhh, you've changed it to 400, now it makes sense

Comment: @RobWhite, apologies 100 was meant to be 400. Thanks for pointing that out. Question amended. The value 400 is constant to simplify the question. In reality it's a variable in C#.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the SQL statement works. Order by is in there, just not in capitals.. Shall amend to make it easier to see.

Comment: You want to return ids in table one that has a matching Id in table2 with the specified number?

Comment: Why use the `In` keyword instead of using `=`?

Comment: I only want to return 400 for the highest value of Table2.Id where (Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still want to use the `In` keyword, the Lambda version would look like:

```
var intList = new List<int>(1) { 400 };
var test = _table1Repository.Table
  .Where(t1 => intList.Contains(_table2Repository.Table
    .Where(t2 => t2.Table1Id == t1.id)
    .OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.Number)
    .First()));
```

The only Caveat is that if there are no values in Table2, `First()` with throw an exception.

An example of mix'd Linq and Lambda:

```
var query1 = _table1Repository.Table
  .OrderBy(t1 => t1.id);

var query2 = (from t1 in query1
  select new { Id = t1.Id, Number = number } );

var query3 = query2.ToList();
```

Comment: Erik I managed to get your solution to work but I'm chaining another LINQ query, so the solution must be LINQ not Lambda.

Comment: var intList = new List<int>(1) { 400 };
var test = _table1Repository.Table
    .Where(t1 => intList.Contains(_table2Repository.Table
    .Where(t2 => t2.Table1Id == t1.Id)
    .OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.Id)
    .Select(t2=>t2.Number)
    .First()));

Comment: Linq and Lamdba expressions are the same, they can both be used together as much as you want.

Comment: When chaining to another LINQ statement I receive the same error as initially (Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Domain.Table2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.). I suspect this has to do with using either .First() or .Contains().

Comment: Without seeing code (you can always update your question with additional code) I have no idea how to help.  I'll update my question with an example.